# Multiple views of viewmodel/entities or multiple viewmodels in one view?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Still trying to find good example of the more complex MVVM scenarios...

Suppose I have one viewmodel - PlayersViewModel that has a collection of Players. In one view I see the collection of Players and add/edit/delete.

Another view is teams, where I assign Players to Teams. So I have another viewmodel - TeamsViewModel. This view also needs a collection of Players. How do I keep the two player lists in sync so changes are shown in both views?

I see a number of options:

1. Add a reference to PlayersViewModel to my Team view (as well as a reference to TeamsViewModel) and use the PlayersViewModel.Players collection in both views
2. Have two different collections that reference the same underlying collection instance (somehow)
3. Create a static property on the Player model like Player.All that returns the collection and the viewmodels manage Players by Player.Add(player), Player.Delete, etc. instead of PlayersViewModel.AddPlayer(player)?

I tend towards #1 at the moment and using app-wide resources so the Team view can call both viewmodels. But then how do I use the selected Players in my PlayersViewModel.Players collection in my TeamsViewModel to add them?

Help please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hard and fast rule is one ViewModel per View, so in my book you are on the right path.  Don't confuse the PlayersViewModel with the Players data: the PlayersViewModel is oriented toward the Players View, NOT the Players data.  In other words, the two are separate, so you do not need to reuse the PlayersViewModel in other ViewModels.  I apologize if I'm not explaining this well...

If you need multiple ViewModels to display with the same instance of the data, then define the data at the App level rather than the Document level.  You could make Players Static or you could have it implement the Singleton pattern: none of those things are specific to the ViewModel because the ViewModel merely consumes the resource.

Comment: Thanks Joel, it seems I'm heading towards this direction and having viewmodels map hard-and-fast to my views. My viewmodels are pretty big at the moment so it looks like I need another service alongside my viewmodels and my entity framework objects - like an intelligent data repository holding things like the current Players collection. Although it does seem some doubling up here somewhere with what EF is supposed to be doing for me.

Comment: Consider adding a Service layer that your ViewModel access for the classes it needs.  The service can use the repository pattern against EF which you could set up with DI or one of hte other methods we discussed above.  Your VM should not be doing all the EF work, it should be communicating with the layer that does.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single ViewModel. Let different views display only what they need. With regard to the collection of players: WPF allows you to have multiple views of the same collection and each with a different filtering/sorting/grouping. See [Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections).

Comment: You mean combine PlayersViewModel and TeamsViewModel into one viewmodel? Or use the same viewmodel for referencing the Player collection? Still not sure how to access the Player collection (or the current listview selection based off it) from my TeamsViewModel (if we don't combine). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean combine two view models. As for selection, why not add a property in your view model and bind to it in the players view, i.e SelectedItem={Binding SelectedPlayer} (of course this is only for single-selection mode). Sorry for my english :).

Comment: Selection is no problem with one viewmodel. But how does this expand? I.e. we now have a collection of Teams in my viewmodel along with Players, what if I need a collection of Matches, do I also put this in the viewmodel? Doesn't this lead to one super viewmodel for the whole app? Thanks!

Comment: In any case, you will have a central repository, which will store all of your objects. Of course, the universal view model - it's bad practice. I offered to combine these two views, because one uses data from the other, and it solves the problem with getting selected objects.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, in order to be easier to understand, I have one viewmodel per view.
This means each custom UserControl has its own ViewModel, dealing with its own actions.
I'm working on a pretty big project with plenty of views, I think it is way cleaner to have one ViewModel per view. It helps me reading my architecture correctly, and therefore I won't mix roles in a unique ViewModel.

However, I cannot ensure you that's the best way to do. I started working in WPF/MVVM 2 weeks ago, I just figured out that it'd be easier to understand with this way (I am used to split my programs into as many classes as possible since I think it's easier to maintain)